# Crystal Reports - table '' could not be found

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an application that runs with Crystal Reports 10. I get this error:

> The table '' could not be found

This doesn't happen with the same database that this report was built with, but when I change the database name, it shows this error.

please help .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably the table has a different name. Can you check the other db and run the same query? Maybe its a view or there's differences in naming.